# Adicionar parâmetro usando PagedList no detalhamento do registro e nos links de páginas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

Alguém sabe me informar como posso manter um parâmetro entre as diversas páginas do PagedList?

A situação é a seguinte: Eu usei o `Scope_Identity` na hora de criar uma linha em uma tabela, pois fiz o `Id` do item criado de parâmetro para outra *action*, essa outra *action* trabalha com *Partial View* e PagedList.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
// Código do método post de inserir a informação no bd

 [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Create")]
    public ActionResult Create_POST(Produto produto, int Id)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ProdutoBLL produtoBll = new ProdutoBLL();
            produto.Id = produtoBll.PesquisaId(produto);
            Session["IdProduto"] = produto.Id;
            return RedirectToAction("Catalogo", "Material", new { produto = produto.Id });
        }
        return View();
    }

// Código do método GET que utiliza o Id que acabou de ser criado.   

 [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Gerente,Funcionario")]
    [ActionName("Catalogo")]
    public ActionResult Catalogo(int produto, int? pag, int? mats)
    {
        material.produto = produto;
        return View(materialBll.BuscaMaterial().ToPagedList(pag ?? 1, 3));
    }
```

O problema é o seguinte: o meu parâmetro não é passado para a segunda página do PagedList em diante. Na primeira página tudo funciona, nas demais dá erro e minha URL não apresenta o parâmetro produto.

Comment: Só um alerta, você está usando um código que vai gerar um desempenho ruim, se está trazendo a lista geral da tabela depois usando o `PagedList` para paginar. Você deve utilizar de forma otimizada em um método especifico que virá do banco os dados já paginados. Você está usando Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

[A documentação do PagedList](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList) ou [a do X.PagedList](https://github.com/kpi-ua/X.PagedList) (a versão mais recente) te sugere algo assim:

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { pag = page }) )
```

Este é um problema comum ([escrevi um curso que ensino a resolver ele e mais alguns outros](http://www.codingcraft.com.br/tag/cursos-em-asp-net-mvc/), aliás). O problema não é a paginação em si, mas que os parâmetros da pesquisa não são preservados ao detalhar o registro ou ir para uma página diferente.

Para resolver, você precisa implementar duas *extensions*: uma para o [`HtmlHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx) e outra para o [`UrlHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx). São elas:

### `HtmlHelperExtensions`

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlHelper"></param>
    /// <param name="linkText"></param>
    /// <param name="action"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ActionQueryLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
        string linkText, string action)
    {
        return ActionQueryLink(htmlHelper, linkText, action, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlHelper"></param>
    /// <param name="linkText"></param>
    /// <param name="action"></param>
    /// <param name="routeValues"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ActionQueryLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
        string linkText, string action, object routeValues)
    {
        var queryString =
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

        var newRoute = routeValues == null
            ? htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values
            : new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);

        foreach (string key in queryString.Keys)
        {
            if (!newRoute.ContainsKey(key))
                newRoute.Add(key, queryString[key]);
        }
        return HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext,
            htmlHelper.RouteCollection, linkText, null /* routeName */,
            action, null, newRoute, null);
    }
    public static string ActionReferrerQuery(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
        string linkText, string action, string controller, object routeValues)
    {
        var referrer = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer;
        if (referrer.Query == null) return HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext,
            htmlHelper.RouteCollection, linkText, "Default", action, controller, null, null);

        var queryString = referrer.Query.Replace("?", "");

        var newRoute = routeValues == null
            ? htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values
            : new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString))
        {
            foreach (string key in queryString.Split('&'))
            {
                var keyValuePair = key.Split('=');
                if (!newRoute.ContainsKey(keyValuePair[0]))
                    newRoute.Add(keyValuePair[0], keyValuePair[1]);
            }
        }

        return HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext,
            htmlHelper.RouteCollection, linkText, "Default", action, controller, newRoute, null);
    }
}
```

### `UrlHelperExtensions`

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string ActionQuery(this UrlHelper urlHelper,
        string action, string controller)
    {
        return ActionQuery(urlHelper, action, controller, null);
    }

    public static string ActionQuery(this UrlHelper urlHelper,
        string action, string controller, object routeValues)
    {
        var queryString =
            urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

        var newRoute = routeValues == null
            ? urlHelper.RequestContext.RouteData.Values
            : new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);

        foreach (string key in queryString.Keys)
        {
            if (!newRoute.ContainsKey(key))
                newRoute.Add(key, queryString[key]);
        }

        return UrlHelper.GenerateUrl("Default", action, controller, newRoute, 
            urlHelper.RouteCollection, urlHelper.RequestContext, true);
    }

    public static string ActionReferrerQuery(this UrlHelper urlHelper,
        string action, string controller, object routeValues)
    {
        var referrer = urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer;
        if (referrer.Query == null) return UrlHelper.GenerateUrl("Default", action, controller, null,
            urlHelper.RouteCollection, urlHelper.RequestContext, true);

        var queryString = referrer.Query.Replace("?", "");

        var newRoute = routeValues == null
            ? urlHelper.RequestContext.RouteData.Values
            : new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString))
        {
            foreach (string key in queryString.Split('&'))
            {
                var keyValuePair = key.Split('=');
                if (!newRoute.ContainsKey(keyValuePair[0]))
                    newRoute.Add(keyValuePair[0], keyValuePair[1]);
            }
        }

        return UrlHelper.GenerateUrl("Default", action, controller, newRoute,
            urlHelper.RouteCollection, urlHelper.RequestContext, true);
    }
}
```

Feito isso, você pode usar o link assim:

```
@Html.PagedListPager((PagedList.IPagedList)Model, page => Url.ActionQuery("MinhaActionDePesquisa", "MeuController", new { pag = page }))
```

Os parâmetros serão adicionados automaticamente na paginação.

Para a *View* de detalhamento, use no botão Voltar:

```
<a href="@Url.ActionReferrerQuery("MinhaActionDePesquisa", "MeuController", null)">Voltar para Lista/Pesquisa</a>
```